# create random number and store in database table

Tags: php, jquery

im try to store random number after click on button and store in database table field name 'f_id'. when i click on button, the new random number is generated but its not store in database table field name 'f_id'.. my code is..
my jquery code ////

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
             $(".random").click(function(){
             var number =Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000);

                 console.log(number);

        });


        });
</script>
```

and my html code ////

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <a class="random action btn btn-success btn-sm" href="#" >random number</a>
</body>
</html>
```

plzz tell me i have created database already but not store this value number on database table..
php code...

```
<?php 

function mytable($number){
          $result = mysqli_query( $this->conn,"INSERT INTO school(f_id) VALUES ('$number')");
              return $result;

}


 ?>
mytable($number);
```

how to connect jquery var number in php code mytable under variable number... plzz solved

Comment: Google `$.post` jQuery Ajax's implementation

Comment: Why not just create the random number using PHP?

Comment: 1) Where does `$number` come from? 2) Your call to `mytable($number);` is OUTSIDE the `<?php ?>` tags so wont actually call the function.

Comment: If the column `f_id` is, as I would suspect, an ID column why use a random number an not an `auto-increment`? What happens if your script generates the same number more than once?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your PHP function using ajax (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) and send your random number.
You can then access it via $_POST['number'] on the server side.

```
$.post( "mytable.php", function({number: number}) {

});
```

Php:

```
function mytable($number)
      $result = mysqli_query( $this->conn,"INSERT INTO school(f_id) VALUES ('$number')");
          return $result;
}
mytable($_POST['number']);
```

Comment: Your code is as vulnerable to sql injection as the code of OP. Also there is absolutely no reason to use post here. You should use get. (I tried to edit twice, but you always decline my edits....)

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt It makes sense to use $_POST for this - it involves the creation of a record. The SQL injection vulnerability definitely needs addressing though.

Comment: how to use post method and get method i button its not a form its only one button and after click button generate random number and that number store in database table that field name 'f_id'

Comment: i use jquery to generate random number and how use get and post method in here.... plzzz give me complete code

Comment: my button is above show , its only button that put classs

Comment: oli crt plzz te me $_POST['number'] in this case index number undefined plzzz solve becuse i use  button only and its not in form and y create random number using jquery and hoy jquery var number use as index

Comment: @xhander meck You need to put the $.post function in your click event and after your random number generation.

Comment: its not solved plzz you give  me complete code ....edit my code and correct plzzz #oli crt

Answer (score -2):

You need to call your php backend script. This could be done like this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
         $(".random").click(function(){
         var number =Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000);

         console.log(number);
         window.location.href='http://path.to/your_script.php?rnd=' + number 
    });
    });
</script>
```

And in your_script.php:

```
<?php 
function mytable($number){
  $number=intval($number);
  $result = mysqli_query( $this->conn,"INSERT INTO school(f_id) VALUES ('$number')");
  return $result;
}

if(mytable($_GET['rnd'])) {
  echo "It works";
}
else echo "Something went wrong";
```

I but putting a random number as id is "probably not" recommended...

Comment: You should not call the url. Instead you should use an ajax request if you already have jQuery or any other ajax supporting library in use.

Comment: Hmm, I'd say that depends on what you want to achieve

Comment: This is the easiest, and probably most instructive and understandable way

Comment: #manuel    yea but how use ajax in this case and store rondom number in database table

Comment: Manuel: Wrapping this in a jquery get request further obscures what is going on. I think Xhander is a student trying to understand what is happening. I would recommend a submit-button and making the request that way, but with the code OP posted, i still believe this is most instructive.

Comment: Surely it's not as this code will result in a blank page not informing the user of any success / error. Also is your code open to `SQL injection`. Not a good example imho

Comment: DarkBee, i corrected the crappy php-code. agree it was not a working example, I was trying to use OP's own code (function and all) but no, it would not run or give helpful output. However: I don't see how this code is open to sql-injection, please explain?